# Loop through all CSV files in a folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop through only the csv files in a folder that contains many kinds of files and many folders, I just want it to list all of the .csv files in this folder.

Here's what I mean:

```
import os, sys

path = "path/to/dir"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

for file in dirs:
    if file == '*.csv':
        print file
```

I know there is no wildcard variable in python, but is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Python provides [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) which should do this

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('/path/to/dir/*.csv')
```

> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which
>   must be a string containing a path specification. pathname can be
>   either absolute (like /usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile) or relative (like
>   ../../Tools/*/*.gif), and can contain shell-style wildcards. Broken
>   symlinks are included in the results (as in the shell).

Answer (score 59):

Use the glob module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

```
import glob
path = "path/to/dir/*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(fname)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to loop through the folder containing cvs files and print the number and the name of the columns.
Following code worked for me

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r"C:\Users\gumnwe\OneDrive - BP\Desktop\Personal\eiLink\Skin Project\Skin_Project_Data_2020\*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
   df=pd.read_csv(fname)
   my_list=list(df.columns)
   print(len(my_list),my_list)
```