# Loop through binary files that has no extension

Tags: python, binary, iteration

I was looking for ways to loop over files in directory with python, and I found this question:

[Loop through all CSV files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262405/loop-through-all-csv-files-in-a-folder)

The point is that the files I have are binary files, with no file extension at the end.
What I want my program to do is to iterate through all the files that have no extension.

Anyway to apply this using wildcards? (Or any other way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.path.splitext` to check if a file has an extension or not.

See this examples:

```
import os

os.path.splitext("foo.ext")
=> ('foo', '.ext')

os.path.splitext("foo")
=> ('foo', '')
```

So, you can do that:

```
import os

path = "path/to/files"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

for path in dirs:
    if not os.path.splitext(path)[1]:
        print(path)
```

But, beware of "hidden" files which name starts with a dot, ie.: ".bashrc".

You can also check for the existence of a dot in the filename:

```
for path in dirs:
    if "." not in path:
        print(path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was the one worked exactly the way I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you are interested in is

```
[f for f in next(os.walk(folder))[2] if '.' not in f]
```

Comment: It looks good. You could add `import os` and write it inside a method to make it ready-to-go.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `os.listdir()`, and then check whether filename has an extension (check if there is a dot in a filename). Once You get all filenames without dots (that is, without extension), just be sure to check that the filename isn't actually directory name, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob)  and filter out any files with extensions:

```
import glob

for filename in (filename for filename in glob.iglob('*') if '.' not in filename):
    print(filename)
```